Firefox: Cannot disable or remove extension
I have a Firefox extension that cannot be removed or disabled within Firefox (e.g. the controls are greyed out). How can I remove or disable it?


Launch Firefox
Enter in its address bar: about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox
Take note of the "Extension ID" of the extension you want to remove
Suppose the ID is {e68418bc-f2b0-4459-a9ea-3e72b6762b07}. FF extensions are .xpi files under ~/.mozilla/firefox or installed globally. This command will give you the location of the extension:

j@db7280:~$ find / -name "*e6841*" 2>/dev/null
/home/j/.mozilla/firefox/zadeq6cf.default-esr/extensions/{e68418bc-f2b0-4459-a9ea-3e72b6762b07}.xpi



cd to the location and remove (rm <extension-id>.xpi) or disable the extension (mv <extension-id>.xpi <extension-id>.xpi~). Prefix sudo  for globally installed extensions
To re-enable the extension, go to the folder and mv <extension-id>.xpi~ <extension-id>.xpi (prefix sudo  if needed)

Note: Tested on Debian bullseye but should work on all distros (but locations may differ between distros and FF versions)
